# Inserting parameters into a template loop

Tags: bi-publisher

Is it possible to use the parameters declared in the `parameters`' node (see the XDT file) inside a `foreach` loop in the template? I'd have to add a namespace? If yes which one?

File XDT:

```
<dataTemplate name="StoreLayoutLabels" xmlns="http://micros.com/xstore/config/report">
  <labels>
    <!-- Template-specific Text -->
    <label name="HANDHELD_READ" value="_art.inventory.handheld.read"/>
    <label name="MANUAL_CHECK" value="_art.inventory.manual.check"/>
    <label name="OPERATOR1" value="_art.inventory.operator1"/>
    <label name="OPERATOR2" value="_art.inventory.operator2"/>
    <label name="SECTION" value="_art.inventory.section"/>
    <label name="STORE" value="_art.inventory.store"/>
  </labels>
 
  <parameters>
    <!-- System Parameters -->
    <parameter name="GroupName" class="java.lang.String" isForPrompting="false" include_in_output="true"/>
    <parameter name="storeNbr" class="java.lang.String" isForPrompting="false" include_in_output="true"/>
    <parameter name="storeName" class="java.lang.String" isForPrompting="false" include_in_output="true"/>
  </parameters>
    
  <!--Data source and data Structure-->
  <dataSource>
    <dataReference name="Q_STORE_LAYOUT_LABELS"> 
      <ResultFields>
          <ResultField>SectionId</ResultField>
          <ResultField>SectionDescription</ResultField>
      </ResultFields>
    </dataReference>
  </dataSource>
  <dataStructure>
    <group name="STORE_LAYOUT_LABELS" source="Q_STORE_LAYOUT_LABELS">
      <element name="SECTION_ID" value="SectionId"/>
      <element name="SECTION_DESCRIPTION" value="SectionDescription"/>
    </group>
  </dataStructure>
</dataTemplate>
```

Report template:

[image]

For example, `PAR_GROUP_NAME` is represented by the `<?GroupName?>` tag in the template but it doesn't appear after the PDF transformation. The value is shown correctly if the tag is inserted outside the label `F` which represents the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you reference a field, it's looking inside the element you are currently in. So you will need to tell BI Publisher where it is if it's not in the current element. Just add `../` for each level you need to go up the tree, and then once you get into the first common element, you can then go back down.

So if you are in a `<?for-each:dataSource?>`
You can get the parameter attribute value, where the attribute name = GroupName, by doing:

```
<?../parameters/parameter[@name='GroupName']?>
```

Reference:
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E80149_01/bip/BIPRD/GUID-4D9FC5FC-5A72-4CE6-919C-A3E0D6E4900C.htm#BIPRD2597

Comment: No way, although your solution make sense to me. I already tried `<?//PARAMETER[@name="GroupName"]?>` like the working `<?//LABEL[@name="SECTION"]?>`. I tested your solution, upper and lower case, with single and double quote with no luck. Many thanks for taking the time to answer.

Comment: You need the two decimals. If you are still having troubles, please post your XML and full template code that is not working.

Comment: `<?../parameters/parameter[@name='GroupName']?>`  or `<?../PARAMETERS/PARAMETER[@name='GroupName']?>` doesn't work either.  The rendering comes from *Oracle Retail Xstore Point of Service*; the XDT is used for build the XML in memory. I'm trying to figure out how the mapped XML can be accessed...

Comment: I'd need to see the entire logic, not just the single field you are pulling.

Comment: OK, I think I found your problem. The data definition file is NOT what your output XML will look like. The template is ran against the output XML file. From what I'm seeing on something I've done before, your parameter GroupName will become it's own element under the root. Seems like its all upper case too. So try <?../GROUPNAME?> The example I'm looking at is from Oracle EBS (E-Bsuiness Suite)

Comment: I got it! It's definitely `<?../../GroupName?>` simply 2 levels up! Thank you a lot for your effort and kindness sir

Comment: the answer was already here: *Just add ../ for each level you need to go up the tree*

Comment: Gotcha. For what it's worth, <?../../GroupName?> is working related to my last comment. "PARAMETERS" is not an element of the output XML., its only the data definition. Glad we could get it working!